# Optimization a function in R

Tags: r

I have a data set like this:

```
x=c(5, 11, 21, 31, 46, 75, 98, 122, 145, 165, 196,
    224, 245, 293, 321, 330, 350, 420)
```

I wrote a function as follows:

```
f.val=function(theta, x){
    a = theta[1]
    b=theta[2]
    c=theta[3]
    d=theta[4]
    n=nrow(x)
    value= sum(log(a*b*(a*x)^(b-1)+c*d*(c*x)^(d-1)))-a*sum(x^b)-c*sum(x^d)
    return(-value)
}
```

and then I would like to maximise the function `f.val` and then get the estimation of `a, b, c, d`. I used optim function with lower and upper bounds in `R`. I know that the value of `b` should be bigger than `1` and the value `d` should be less that `1`. Also, the value of `a`and `b` should be bigger than zero. I applied the following function but I could not get the result :

```
> optim(c(0, 0, 0, 0), f.val, x=x, method="L-BFGS-B", lower=c(0, 1, 0, 0),
 + upper=c(rep(Inf, 3), 1))

Error in optim(c(0, 0, 0, 0), f.val, x = x, method = "L-BFGS-B", lower =c(0,  :  L-BFGS-B needs finite values of 'fn'
```

I try the following values but still can not get the correct values:

```
optim(c(1e-6, 1e-6, 1e-6, 1e-6), f.val, x=x, method="L-BFGS-B", lower=c(1e-6, 1, 1e-6, 1e-6), upper=c(rep(10000, 3), 1))


 $par
 [1] 0.0000010 1.0000000 0.0333163 0.5695943

 $value
 [1] 91.17824

 $counts
 function gradient 
  60       60 

 $convergence
 [1] 0

 $message
 [1] "CONVERGENCE: REL_REDUCTION_OF_F <= FACTR*EPSMCH"
```

How can I solve this error and get the following result:

```
a = 0 (approximately); b = 2.2589; c = 0.0183 and d = 0.7266
```

Comment: I was evaluating your function putting different values. And it returns NaN or Inf if 2 of 4 theta values is 0. You should think in what values your theta could take

Comment: I do not know how to choose the starting values.

Comment: as @BondedDust says you should find the values `a, b, c, d` that gives greater then 0 the expression inside `log()`